# azure devops release pipeline is copy over ssh is very slow

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, release

I am using Azure Devops Release pipeline "Copy files over SSH" job to copy the files from Artifacts (git branch) to the Ubuntu server. I use self hosted agent which is Windows server. Previously it was taking 60 mins to copy nearly 3 GB of files but now it is taking 7 hours to complete it.

I tried

1. restarting the agent
2. upgraded to latest version,
3. verified the network speed it is more than 500 MBs (this is within the agent server.

Still issue persists.

The Agent server and target Ubuntu Server both resides in same Vnet but different subnet.

This is not only happening in one release pipeline currently we tested it is happening in 2 release pipeline.

please help me in troubleshooting this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The issue is caused by the upgrade version of the task. Now Copy files over SSH task has rolled back to the version 0.231.0. It can work as expected. You can try to run the release pipeline again and check if it can work.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the same issue when using the Copy files over SSH task version 0.236.1.

You can check the task version in the Pipeline log:

[image]

This is a known issue when using the Copy files over SSH task version 0.236.1.

Refer to this ticket: [Copy files over SSH task (0.236.1 ) is now extremely slow](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Copy-files-over-SSH-task-02361--is-n/10618164)

The issue has been reported to the Product Group. You can keep monitoring this ticket to check the update.

For a workaround, you can change to use YAML Pipeline to run the Copy files over SSH task and roll back to use the task version:0.231.1

For example:

```
- task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0.231.1
  inputs:
    contents: '**'
    ....
```

**Update:**

Product Group has rolled back the Copy files over SSH task to version: 0.231.0.

[image]

Now the task can work as expected in Build Pipeline and Release Pipeline.